# Converting Association to Matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning, associations

Imagine I have the following association, where the keys are given as pairs of natural numbers

```
assoc = <|{1, 1} -> 0, {2, 1} -> 1, {1, 3} -> 0, {3, 2} -> 0, {1, 2} -> 1, {3, 1} -> 0,
    {2, 3} -> 0, {3, 3} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 0|>
```

To get the connectivity matrix defined by this association, where in `{i, j}`, `i` is the row and `j` is the column, I can do

```
Partition[Values@KeySort@assoc, 3]
Out[]= {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
```

Is there a faster way to directly get the previous matrix (or list of lists)?

Comment: Try `SparseArray[Normal[assoc]]` or (if you know the dimensions in advance) `SparseArray[Normal[assoc],{3,3}]`.

Comment: Thinking of it, `SparseArray[Keys[assoc] -> Values[assoc], {3, 3}]` should perform better for long assiciations.

Comment: `SparseArray[KeyValueMap[Rule, assoc]]` would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nodes = Union@Catenate@Keys@assoc
edges = Cases[Normal@assoc, ({x_, y_} -> 1) :> x -> y]
AdjacencyMatrix@Graph[nodes, edges]  (* a SparseArray *)
```